# Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I have this syntax error as below:
Code:

```
select '99999' as Code, N'Tat ca' as Name, N'ALL - Tat ca' as Display_Name ,'' as AreaName UNION select CONVERT(Code,VARCHAR) as Code,Name,  CONVERT(Code,VARCHAR)+'-'+Name as Display_Name ,AreaName FROM devices;
```

Error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'VARCHAR) as Code,Name, 
>   CONVERT(Code,VARCHAR)+'-'+Name as Display_Name ,AreaName' at line 3

I don't know how to fix this error. Look forward to your helps.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is only CONVERT part user CHAR

```
 select '99999' as Code, N'Tat ca' as Name, N'ALL - Tat ca' as Display_Name ,'' as AreaName
FROM <TABLE_NAME> UNION select CONVERT(Code,CHAR) as Code,Name, CONVERT(Code,CHAR)+'-'+Name as Display_Name ,AreaName FROM devices
```

Comment: `SELECT` without from is permitted: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_convert.asp) you can not convert to `VARCHAR`.
Change to `CHAR`.

```
select '99999' as Code, N'Tat ca' as Name, N'ALL - Tat ca' as Display_Name ,'' as AreaName FROM DUAL;
UNION 
select CONVERT(Code,CHAR) as Code,Name,  CONVERT(Code,CHAR)+'-'+Name as Display_Name ,AreaName FROM devices;
```